# Set JSplitPane divider location from the right

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jsplitpane

As far as I know, the `setDivider()` method of JSplitPane can take an int which is an absolute position from the left.  For example, `someSplitPane.setDivider(120);` will set the divider 120px from the left.  Is there any way I can do the same thing, but set the divider an absolute position from the right?

Simple implementation:

```java
public class Window extends JFrame {
    
    JSplitPane splitpane;
    
    public Window() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    private void initComponents() {
        setTitle("Debugging");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        
        splitpane = new JSplitPane();
        System.out.println(splitpane.getSize().width); // prints 0
        splitpane.setDividerLocation(splitpane.getSize().width - 120);
        getContentPane().add(splitpane);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Window().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have written this code isolated from any existing code, and I reproduce the error.  What looks to be happening is the JFrame is instantiating and appears on the desktop, and then about a second later, a 0 (from the commented print statement) is output to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you create your GUI correctly by using the EDT you can add the following in the constructor of your class where you create the splitPane:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
{
        Dimension d = splitPane.getSize();
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(d.width - 120);
});
```

This will add code to the EDT. So after the frame is visible and the split pane has been given a size, the divider location will be reset.

Comment: I am indeed using EDT.  Inside the EDT I instantiate a new JFrame which, in turn, instantiates the JScrollPane in its constructor.  I will update the question to reflect this information.  I tried your solution (along with `splitpane.getWidth() - 100`) and both times, the result is -100, not the width - 100.

Comment: Works fine for me. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: alas as is usual with my problems, there is something else flying under my radar.  give me a moment to try to replicate the problem as minimally as possible instead of making assumptions.

Comment: I have updated the code to be as minimal as I think necessary to still reproduce the problem (after testing it this time to be sure).

Comment: I said you needed to add the above code in the constructor of your class. The point is your entire GUI is created on the EDT, but you don't know the size of the split pane until the frame is visible and all components have been given a size. So you need the second invokeLater().

Comment: forgive me for being dense, @camickr.  Your solution is correct and makes sense to me.  IDK why I never thought of doing that since I suspected the reason for the error in my code.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to your code and created this GUI.

[image: JSplitPane Right]

I used a `JFrame` instead of extending a `JFrame`.

I set the preferred size of the `JSplitPane`, rather than the `JFrame`.  Generally, you care more about the size of the `JSplitPane` than the `JFrame`.  Usually, the `JSplitPane` will have two `JPanels` with Swing components, so you don't have to specify a preferred size at that point.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JSplitPaneRight {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new JSplitPaneRight();
        });
    }
    
    public JSplitPaneRight() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    public void initComponents() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSplitPane Right");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createSplitPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JSplitPane createSplitPane( ) {
        JSplitPane splitpane = new JSplitPane();
        splitpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        int width = splitpane.getPreferredSize().width;
        System.out.println(width); // prints 0
        splitpane.setDividerLocation(width - 120);
        
        return splitpane;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a good way to do this if you know the size of the JSplitPane.

Comment: @Mike: As I explained in the answer, once you create the two JPanels with Swing components, you no longer have to define the preferred size of the JSplitPane.  The layout managers will calculate the preferred size.